# Mapping a Picture URL to a Calendar Content Search Webpart in SP 2013

Tags: calendar, content-search-web-part, picture

I created a Calendar library and added two new site columns; one type an Image and the other a Hyperlink. Then mapped an image to both, that I want to use as a reference with the Picture URL.

However, I cannot find the field(s) in the Picture URL selection list. How do I get them on the list, or know which one to use?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you would like to display an image in your CSWP from a hyperlink column?

Comment: Yes, using the "Picture on left, 3 lines on right" format.

Comment: I will try to answer this tomorrow as I'm on my way home and do not have access to my display templates. :)